# Alt-tab brings app switcher instead of switching

Tags: gnome, application-switcher

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with Gnome 3. Something that really bothers me with the app switcher is that when I press `Alt-Tab` the app switcher is brought to the front but the currently active window is selected. This means that to switch to another app I have to press `Alt-Tab` twice. It also means that pressing `Alt-Tab` just one does absolutely nothing (I remember a time when that switch an application without displaying the app switcher).

Is there a configuration to fix this?

Comment: Strange, this is not the normal behaviour. You may want to temporarily create a new account and log in there to see if the issue is reproduced in a clean account.

Comment: You're right! A new account does not have this behaviour. Do you know where I can find the offending config? Preferably without deleting my home directory. I am sure it's not in my `.config` since I copied that to the test account and that did not replicate this behaviour.

Comment: Suspect all installed Gnome Shell extensions first.